# Symfony - api platform authentication in tests

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, httpclient, api-platform.com

In my Symfony project I am trying to pass authentication in **tests** using [THIS](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/testing/) exact example as I am using **API PLATFORM** in my project.

Error is `404` with response I am getting:

> Unable to find the controller for path authentication_token. The route is wrongly configured.

When logging in on that same route I have successful response but form some reason the same thing is not passing when implementing in tests.

Did I maybe forgot to define something. It is strange that same endpoint and authentication works outside tests and no otherwise.

Does anyone have a clue?